# How can I read every 5 seconds in pyspark with kafka readStream?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I want to read a topic every 5 seconds; with older versions of `pyspark` I can use kafka-utils and window method, but currently, I cannot use that.

Now I am loading data from `kafka` with `spark` with the following code

```
spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 'localhost:9092') \
    .option("subscribe", 'data') \
    .load()
```

But whit this, I am reading all data.

So I want to know how I can read the data with batches size of 1 second every 5 seconds if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Structured streaming reads the data in microbatches. You can still add windowing if you need to group data into larger batches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to aggregate and group by something every 5 second interval, refer [documentation on windowing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time)

This should define a tumbling window

```
kafka_df \
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "5 seconds") \
    .groupBy(
        window(kafka_df.timestamp, "5 seconds", "1 second"),
        kafka_df.value)
```

Comment: Finnaly works, but when I use the append mode I got error, how can I show the results every 10 seconds with that?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: was a "typo", I solved I thing, thanks for all your help.